# can't install webmin on ubuntu server

Tags: server, apt, wget, webmin

I have an Ubuntu server installed and I want to install webmin on it but I can't. I have tried everything but reached no solution. I also set this

```
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http:// webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib
```

in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.
 Can someone help me?

Here is the detail of the problem:

```
t@aksoy:~$ wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.700_all.deb
--2014-08-18 21:31:47--  
http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.700_all.deb
Resolving prdownloads.sourceforge.net (prdownloads.sourceforge.net)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘prdownloads.sourceforge.net’
```

PS: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
```

in your `sources.list` and run the command

```
wget -q http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

to import the key

after that

```
apt-get update
apt-get install webmin
```

this is a good tutorial at [UbuntuHandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/12/install-webmin-official-repository-ubuntu/)

Comment: When I run the command: wget -q http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add - I get an "error" it says : "gpg: no valid openPGP data found

Comment: this is another problem i think. this might help http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196704

Answer (score 0):

here is your single issue in your original post of code.

deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib

deb http:// webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib

you have a space in second deb line after http://

Sorry for posting on this years later just incase anyone runs across.